# What is Alfresco's CMIS 1.1 WSDL binding URL?

Tags: wsdl, alfresco, cmis, opencmis

[CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) is a protocol with several optional bindings: **Atom**, **WSDL**, **Browser**.

According to [Alfresco's documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/pra/1/concepts/cmis-request-url-format-onpremise.html):

> Currently Alfresco supports the **atom** binding for the CMIS **1.0** protocol,
>   and both the **atom** and **browser** bindings for the CMIS **1.1** protocol.

In fact, Alfresco also has a (undocumented?) **WSDL** binding for CMIS **1.0** at URL `http://server/alfresco/cmisws/cmis?wsdl`.

Similarly, is there a **WSDL** binding for CMIS **1.1**, and if yes, at what URL?

I have tried `http://server/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/wsdl` and many similar URLs but no luck so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web Services binding is not supported for CMIS 1.1 in Alfresco 4.2.e Community Edition or 4.2.0 Enterprise. Maybe it will be in a future release but I doubt it.

Comment: By the way, I tried to update http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS#RESTful_AtomPub_Binding with the new addresses. But as usual the wiki is extremely slow so login times out :-/

Comment: Thanks for trying. IT is busy working on upgrades. Not sure if that's what caused the problem.